# Count with where is faster then without?

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have table with around 60 000 rows. I have this two queries that are drastically different in speed. Can you explain why?

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table;
300ms - 58936 rows

Explain:
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_length | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | table | NULL | index | NULL | table_id_index | 8 | NULL | 29325 | 100.00 | using index |

---

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE dummy = 1;
50ms - 58936 rows

Explain:
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_length | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | table | NULL | index | NULL | dummy_index | 5 | const | 14662 | 100.00 | using index |

Comment: Did you benchmark this properly (run both multiple times, in different orders, to avoid cache warming effects)? What does the execution plan say? Is it different?

Comment: Execution plan can answer this precisely

Comment: @Thilo, yes. Cache has nothing to do with it

Comment: @YatiSawhney, well faster query is using `dummy` index, instead of `id` index. Why dummy index is faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

- `COUNT(id)` *may* be slower than `COUNT(*)`.  The former checks `id` for being `NOT NULL`; the latter simply counts the rows.  (If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, then this is unlikely to make any measurable difference.)
- The Optimizer may decide to scan the entire table rather than use an index.
- The Optimizer may pick an irrelevant index if not forced to by the `WHERE` clause.  In your example, any index with `id` can be used for the first, and any index with *both* `dummy` and `id` for the second.
- If you run the same query twice, it may run much faster the second time due to caching.  This can happen even for a 'similar' query.  *I suspect this is the "answer".*  I often see a speedup of 10x if the first run was from disk and the second found everything needed in cache (the buffer_pool).
- To get more insight, do `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`
- The optimal index for your second query is `INDEX(dummy, id)`.

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT - the result is that first query uses id_index, second query uses dummy_index

Comment: @AidOnline01 please add explain results to the question.

Comment: @weirdan, I have added

Comment: `dummy_index` is shorter (`key_len=5` as opposed to `key_len=8` for `PRIMARY`). So it's both faster to read it, and more pages would fit into memory.

Comment: @weirdan - For InnoDB...  The PK is clustered with the data, so "8" should be replaced by the size of the entire row.  The "5" needs to be 5+8, since the PK is silented tacked onto each secondary key.

Comment: Good points. So it's still very likely that the secondary index is much smaller then the primary - thus faster.

Comment: @weirdan - The "row" of a secondary index is necessarily no wider than a row of the table and is possibly a lot narrower.  The secondary index contains a subset of the columns of the whole table.  (Due to block splits, fragmentation, etc, the _disk space_ could be a little more for a secondary index containing most or all of the columns.)